# Need some aid coding multiple chained if-statements

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, html-table, label

I'm trying to return a value of in a cell of this table (code provided below):

```html
<table id="gpa-calc-table" class="d_g d_gl" summary="List of grade items and their values">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="visibility:hidden;" class="fgskip">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gpa_calc_headings">
      <th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gl">Course Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gr" style="padding-left:0.1em;">Class Grade</th>
      <th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gr" style="padding-left:0.1em;">Grade Points</th>
      <th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gr" style="padding-left:0.1em;">Credit Units</th>
      <th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gr" style="padding-left:0.1em;">Total Grade Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class=" d_firstRow">

      <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich" id="gpa_calc_table_r1t">
        <label class="subject1" contenteditable=""><strong>First Class</strong></label>
      </th>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r1_cg" contenteditable="">91%<br></label>
      </td>

      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r1_gp" contenteditable="">
    <script>
function func1() {           
 var x = document.getElementById('r1_cg');
        var a = 49.9%;
        var b = 54.9%;
        var c = 59.9%;
        var d = 64.9%;
        var e = 69.9%;
        var f = 74.9%;
        var g = 79.9%;
        var h = 89.9%;
        if (x>h) {return 4.2};
        if (x>g) {return 4.0};
        if (x>f) {return 3.5}; 
        if (x>e) {return 3.0};
        if (x>d) {return 2.5};
        if (x>c) {return 2.0};
        if (x>b) {return 1.5};
        if (x>a) {return 1.0};}
     
    </script></label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r1_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r1_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP<br></label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class=" d_secondRow">

      <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich">
        <label class="subject2" contenteditable=""><strong>Second Class</strong></label>
      </th>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r2_cg" contenteditable="">0-100%</label>
      </td>

      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r2_gp" contenteditable="">0-4.2</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r2_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r2_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP</label>
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr class=" d_thirdRow">

      <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich">
        <label class="subject3" contenteditable=""><strong>Third Class</strong></label>
      </th>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r3_cg" contenteditable="">0-100%</label>
      </td>

      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r3_gp" contenteditable="">0-4.2</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r3_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r3_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class=" d_fourthRow">

      <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich">
        <label class="subject4" contenteditable=""><strong>Fourth Class</strong></label>
      </th>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r4_cg" contenteditable="">0-100%</label>
      </td>

      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r4_gp" contenteditable="">0-4.2</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r4_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r4_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class=" d_fifthRow">

      <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich">
        <label class="subject5" contenteditable=""><strong>Fifth Class</strong></label>
      </th>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r5_cg" contenteditable="">0-100%</label>
      </td>

      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r5_gp" contenteditable="">0-4.2</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r5_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r5_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class=" d_sixthRow">

      <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich">
        <label class="subject6" contenteditable=""><b>Sixth Class</b><br></label>
      </th>

      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r6_cg" contenteditable="">0-100%</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r6_gp" contenteditable="">0-4.2</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r6_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
      </td>
      <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
        <label id="r6_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This code depicts one row in the table (similar application will be applied to other rows

```
`<tr class=" d_firstRow">

  <th scope="row" class="d_gt d_ich" id="gpa_calc_table_r1t">
    <label class="subject1" contenteditable=""><strong>First Class</strong></label>
  </th>
  <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
    <label id="r1_cg" contenteditable="">91%<br></label>
  </td>

  <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
    <label id="r1_gp" contenteditable="">
<script>
    function func1(){
    var x = document.getElementById('r1_cg');
    var a = 49.9%;
    var b = 54.9%;
    var c = 59.9%;
    var d = 64.9%;
    var e = 69.9%;
    var f = 74.9%;
    var g = 79.9%;
    var h = 89.9%;
    if (x>h) {return 4.2};
    if (x>g) {return 4.0};
    if (x>f) {return 3.5}; 
    if (x>e) {return 3.0};
    if (x>d) {return 2.5};
    if (x>c) {return 2.0};
    if (x>b) {return 1.5};
    if (x>a) {return 1.0};}

</script></label>
  </td>
  <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
    <label id="r1_cu" contenteditable="">0-5</label>
  </td>
  <td class="d_gn d_gr d_gt">
    <label id="r1_tgp" contenteditable="">CU*GP<br></label>
  </td>

</tr>`
```

The < script> in that I'm trying to have return say, 4.0, if the grade is between 79.9% and 89.9%, or 2.0 if the grade is between 59.9% and 64.9%, and so on. It may be helpful to note that this is for a GPA calculator, and I need the if(x>h) to have priority over the lower 'if' functions in the chain, etc. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Return to what? That code isn't inside of a function. What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: return the values depicted after the 'return'. Also, new to javascript and trying to learn best I can

Comment: Ya, but to where? Your code isn't valid, so I'm trying to figure out what your intent is. `return` only makes sense when used inside of a function. You're using `return` outside of a function which will cause errors (which you didn't mention). What do you want to do with the value you're attempting to return?

Comment: To the label it's set within. I'm basically saying, if such and such value is '3.5' in cell A....return value 'x' in cell B. (With the code being in cell B)(Also added the function part I neglected)